# jQuery: Dynamically passing UTM parameters to a link in the page

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, hyperlink

I'm looking to use jQuery to dynamically append a link in my page with UTM information from the current URL.

For example:

My current page URL can have many different UTM parameters, but I'd like to parse out the information that is in between "source" and "content".  Then I'd like to pass those parameters to a link in the page given the parameters below.

The current page url is:

*www.current-page.com/?Campaign=Test&Medium=Email&Source=**My%Newsletter**&Content=&Term=*

The call to action button/link points to the following by default:

*www.next-page.com?**source=website***

I'd like to parse out the **My%20Newsletter** part of the current URL, and then change the button/link href from source=website to **source=My%20Newsletter**.

I have the code below, but it still needs some work.

```
var tracking_param = "source=My%20Newsletter";
$('a.my-class').each(function() {
  var param_linker;
  var href = $(this).attr('href')
  if(href !== undefined) {
  if(href.indexOf('?') >=0) { 
    param_linker = "&"
  }
  else {
    param_linker = "?"
  }
  var final_url = href + param_linker + tracking_param;
  $(this).attr('href', final_url);
  }
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
$('a.my-class').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href')
    if(href !== undefined) {
        var url = document.URL;
        int index = url.indexOf("Source=");
        if(index != -1){
            url = url.substr(index + 7) // 7 = length of "Source="
            indexx = url.indexOf("&");
            if(indexx != -1)
                url = url.substr(0, indexx + 1);
            // now url contains the value
            href = href.replace("website", url);
            $(this).attr('href', href);
        }
    }
});
```